# Excel connection in javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

How do I pull data and display it in html from a Excel file using Javascript?

I have a code like this:

```
var myFirstjson = { "firstName":"John",
                    "LastName":"Lenon",
                    "age":23,
                                                                                                              };
document.writeln(myFirstjson["firstName"]+"<br/>"); 
document.writeln(myFirstjson["LastName"]+"<br/>");
document.writeln(myFirstjson["age"]+"<br/>");
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

What I need to do is parameterize the values in the first name last name and age from an Excel file located in `d:\file.xls`

Comment: Please just edit your question if you need to add information.

Answer (score 1):

You either need a server side script to prepare the data for you, usually it's to convert to json format.

or you could save your data to csv and paste that into a text area for javascript to do whatever you want it to.

why are you needing to use javascript with excel, if it's for scripting then i suggest you use vba instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually asking "How to read data from my local computer in a HTML program (i.e. JavaScript)". If you're running on IE, Chrome, any Web browser due to security concerns the answer is no way. But, try Microsoft HTA and search for ado = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream"); and fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); those are the two available interfaces to access local computer file system. Use ADO if your data contains none ANSI characters e.g. utf-8.